# Can't add group to Django user

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to add a group to a Django user, and I just can't do that. The code is very simple:

```
group = Group.objects.get(name='mygroup')   # Works
request.user.groups.add(group)              # No error
```

However, after the addition request.user.groups is `auth.Group.None` (just like it was before the addition).

I get exactly the same behavior if I add the user through the group:

```
group.user_set.add(user)
```

I'm running this code as part of a unit test, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you show the test, please?

Comment: The test is quite elaborate, sending multiple requests to set up the environment and then performs an operation that involves a few classes.

Comment: I'll add more information

Comment: While trying to add more information the behavior suddenly disappeared, and everything is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use 
`request.user.groups.all()` instead of `request.user.groups` to get the groups of a user

Comment: Of course, this did not make a difference back when the problem persisted. Now it's working. It'll probably come back to bite me a month after the system is launched.

Comment: Bugs make life more beautiful! Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

Once user added to group use save() method.

```
group = Group.objects.get(name='mygroup')
request.user.groups.add(group)
request.user.save()
```